# kettle etl transformation hop between steps doesn't work

Tags: kettle

I am using PDI 6 and new to PDI. I created these two tables:

```
    create table test11 (
     a int
    )

    create table test12 (
     b int
    )
```

I created a transformation in PDI, simple ,just two steps

[image]

In first step:

```
    insert into test11 (a)
    select 1 as c;
```

In second step:

```
    insert into test12 (b)
    select 9 where 1 in (select a from test11);
```

I was hoping second step execute **AFTER** first step, so the value 9 will be inserted. But when I run it, nothing got inserted into table test12. It looks to me the two steps are executed in parallel. To proved this, I eliminated second step and put the sql in step 1 like this

```
    insert into test11 (a)
    select 1 as c;
    insert into test12 (b)
    select 9 where 1 in (select a from test11);
```

and it worked. So why? I was thinking one step is one step so next step will wait until it finishes, but it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PDI Transformations, the step initialization and execution happen in parallel. So if you are having multiple steps in a single transformation, these steps will be executed in parallel and the data movement happens in round-robin fashion *(by default)*. This is primarily the reason why your two execute SQL steps do not work, since both the steps are executed in parallel. The same is not the case with PDI Jobs. Jobs work in a sequential fashion unless it is configured to run in parallel.

Now for your question, you can try to do any one of the below steps:

1. Create two separate transformations with the SQL steps and place it inside a JOB. Execute the job in sequence.
2. You can try using the [Block this step until finish](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Block+this+step+until+steps+finish) in transformation which will wait for a particular step to get execute. This is one way to avoid parallelism in transformations. The design of your transformation will similar to as below: 
   *Data grids are a dummy input step. No need to assign any data to the data grids.*

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That works thanks!. But I am wondering what's the best practice in this case? I guess it's option 1. And for option 2 why I can't do execute sql script  -> Block this step until steps finish -> Execute sql script 2 ? (tried and it won't work)